# Viewing Contents of Deployed Ruleset on Rule Execution Server using REST API

Tags: rest, execution, rules, jrules, ibm-odm

How to view the deployed ruleset archive content using REST API(GET) in ODM 8.5?

I am aware of viewing the deployed rule application archive contents on the RES Console including the option to select b2x, bom, irl, xml, empty directories

Comment: "I  am aware of viewing the deployed rule application archive contents on the RES Console including the option to select b2x, bom, irl, xml, empty directories" where do you see this content?

Comment: 1) Logon to RES Console 2) Click on your rule app 3) Click on your rule set 4) Click on your ruleset 5) Scroll down on page to see the options Ruleset Parameters, Managed URI's, Show Properties, Show Monitoring Options, Show HTDS Options, Show Archive Content. 6) Please click on Show Archive Content 7) Here you will find to the right on the same page option to view the b2x/bom/irl/xml/Empty directories Does that answer the question you asked JSR?

Comment: yes, I am aware of this, so basically you are looking for same thing through REST API. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, please let me know, if the details of the ruleset and the properties set on the rules like description can be obtained using REST Api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to view deployed ruleset archive content on Rule Execution Server using REST API. Basically these REST API calls are divided in four parts.

```
ruleapps
rulesets
libraries
xoms
```

You can call any of the available methods for above four artifacts but not to view archive content.

Comment: Not even the monitoring filters or setting INFO_EXECUTION_EVENTS/INFO_EXECUTION_DURATION/INFO__TOTAL_RULES_FIRED/INFO_TOTAL_TASKS_EXECUTED, was able to retrieve the rule names by development of client though but not the individual properties as in the requirement for me to develop though... Thanks for the Answer JSR

Comment: @ ACK , Thank you. If you are fine, you can accept this as answer.

Comment: I have accepted as an answer.I feel there is a JMX way to interact with the deployed rule set archives, not using the REST API though

Comment: Thanks ! And You can open a new thread for this JMX question. let people do the research :-)